# Resize Inline VF page based on content is really delivered?

Tags: visualforce, page-layout, summer-16, inline

I was surprised to find [Resizing Inline VF page based on content](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000jbvRAAQ) idea has been delivered in Summer'16 release.But I couldn't find information how  about it, anywhere in the Summer'16 release notes which is really confusing.

I checked if there's any new option like `resize` checkbox available in the page layout editor, but there's nothing new there and also I checked the User Interface setting too.

Is this feature really delivered? Or Am i missing something here?

Comment: They've actually removed the `ideaStatus` from that particular `Idea`, if it was ever posted as delivered. Perhaps you confused it with [this Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Br8CAAS)?